# WeibullGen Parameters using umontreal.iro.lecuyer.randvar package java

Tags: java, random, parameters

I am trying to generate weibull random numbers using WeibullGen from umontreal.iro.lecuyer.randvar package this is my code

```
RandomStream stream = new MRG32k3a();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
   int result = WeibullGen.nextDouble(stream, alp, lam,bet);
   System.out.println(result);
}
```

But I am a little confused about the parameters I mean does lam means the scale or the rate parameters, I think alp means the shape parameter. finally, I am confused about the last parameter bet what it present. I tried to look online but it wasn't clear to me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the answer alp is the shape parameter, lam is the rate parameter but still confused about bet I think its some upper limit but not sure any suggestion?

Comment: I think bet is the lower limit for the generated random numbers and its almost always 1.0 because at t=0 the weibull random number will be zero.

Comment: What do the javadocs say?

Comment: What I explained above.